# C++ cannot create new key in registry

Tags: c++, windows, registry

I really need your help. I tried everything but the result is always the same, nothing. Please advise.

And this is my code

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <windef.h>

using namespace std;

int main (void)
{
    HKEY hKey;
    LONG regOpenResult;

    const char PATH[] = "C:\\Users\\les\\Documents\\visual studio 2010\\Projects\\registryTester\\Debug\\registryTester.exe";

    RegCreateKeyExW(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,
            L"SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run",
            0,
            NULL,REG_OPTION_VOLATILE,
            KEY_SET_VALUE,
            NULL,
            &hKey,
            NULL
    );

    RegSetValueExW(hKey, L"regTest", 0, REG_SZ, (BYTE*)PATH, strlen(PATH));

    RegCloseKey(hKey);
}
```

Comment: could you provide any information as to what error (message) you are encountering? Also please specify the OS you are working on (is it x64)? Does your process have sufficient rights to access `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE`?

Comment: Thanks . at last i have done that. You where right app does not have perimission on local machine .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the return status of each API call!!!!  Use GetLastError () for each failure.

Knowing the error should lead you to resolve the problem.

Otherwise, you're flying completely blind...

Yes, PATH shouldn't be an 8-bit character string if you're calling a 16-bit Unicode API.  But it's not necessarily the only problem.

And yes, "permissions" could very definitely be an issue if you're using Vista, Windows 7 or higher.

Answer (score 4):

You're using the unicode version of the RegSetValueEx, but passing it a char* string. You should change the declaration of PATH to:

`const wchar_t PATH[] = L"C:\\Users\\les\\Documents\\visual studio 2010\\Projects\\registryTester\\Debug\\registryTester.exe";`

And use `wcslen` instead of `strlen` since it's a wchar_t string. Since it's measured in bytes (not characters) and needs to include the null terminator, the size parameter should be `wcslen(PATH)*2+2`.

Comment: Actually, if he has VS2008 or higher, he's probably defaulting to Unicode anyway.  Of course, PATH would still be wrong .. but strlen and friends should work OK.  And he can use "RegCreateKeyEx()" instead of "RegCreateKeyExW()" etc...

Comment: EDIT: updated as the cbSize parameter is measured in bytes (not characters), and needs to include the size of the null terminator.

Comment: `wcslen(PATH)*sizeof(wchar_t) + 2` would be both clearer and more correct.